# How to get features/attributes of a data point if its distance from the cluster's center is known?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a `DataFrame X` with columns `A`, `B` and `C`. I applied `kMeans` clustering with `n_clusters`=4 and got `euclidean distance` of 10 nearest data points from each cluster's center. Example, for `i`th cluster, I did this:-

```
#getting 10 nearest points from ith cluster center
print(np.sort(kmeans.transform(X)[:, i])[: 10])
#output:-
array([0.06096257, 0.07785726, 0.09155965, 0.09301038, 0.09741242,
   0.1016601 , 0.10242911, 0.10314227, 0.10775149, 0.10895064])
```

Now, I want to get features `A`, `B` and `C` for these 10 data points. How to pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `argsort` if you want to get the *indexes* of the smallest values.

Mapping distances to points is complicated.